# Skip Executing other Validation Rules in the Fluent validation Ruleset, if one of them fails

Tags: c#, validation, servicestack, fluent, fluentvalidation

Is there any way to skips executing the validation rules in the Ruleset if one of them fails.

I have this following rules for my API endpoint

param1, param2, param3

```
RuleSet  => 
     RuleFor(req => req.param1).NotEmpty().WithMessage("param1 is missing.");
     RuleFor(req => req.param2).NotEmpty().WithMessage("param2 is missing.");
     RuleFor(req => req.param3).NotEmpty().WithMessage("param3 is missing.");
     RuleFor(req => req.param1).Must((req, param1) => IsValidRequest(req)).WithMessage("Invalid request.");
```

In my IsValidRequest(req) I again have to verify for param1, param2, param3 exist before doing my custom validation as even if the above rules fails all other validations will still continue to try.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605534/stop-fluent-validation-on-first-failure

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, FluentValidation uses `Continue` cascade mode for invoking validators in rule definition (i.e. it invokes all validators). You should use `StopOnFirstFailure` mode to stop execution after first validator fails:

```
ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;
```

Note that this will set `StopOnFirstFailure` mode globally. If you want to specify this mode for particular validators, you can use property of validator class:

```
public class RequestValidator : AbstractValidator<Request>
{
   public RequestValidator()
   {
       CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;

       RuleFor(req => req.param1)
          .NotEmpty().WithMessage("param1 is missing.")
          .Must((req, param1) => IsValidRequest(req)).WithMessage("Invalid request.");
       RuleFor(req => req.param2).NotEmpty().WithMessage("param2 is missing.");
       RuleFor(req => req.param3).NotEmpty().WithMessage("param3 is missing.");
   }
}
```

In the example above `Must` validator will not be executed if `NotEmpty` validator fails.

---

If you want to execute `Must` validator only when all three parameters are not empty, then `When` is the best option:

```
When(req => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.param1) 
         && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.param2)
         && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.param3), () => {
     RuleFor(req => req.param1)
        .Must((req, param1) => IsValidRequest(req)).WithMessage("Invalid request.");
});
```

You can move precondition check to separate method:

```
 private bool AllParametersSpecified(Request req)
 {
     return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.param1) 
         && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.param2)
         && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.param3);
 }
```

And condition will be much more readable:

```
When(AllParametersSpecified, () => {
     RuleFor(req => req.param1)
        .Must((req, param1) => IsValidRequest(req)).WithMessage("Invalid request.");
});
```

Comment: What if my function IsValidRequest need all param1, param2, param3 to be not null.Thank you for the quick reply Sergey.

Comment: This is great, but I still have one issue with it. I am not able to give users an individual message of param1 is missing or param2 is missing before calling my IsValidRequest function. Now I am restricted to give the error message only for Invalid Request.

Comment: @anveshtummala just don't remove validation rules for params. They will do validation. And if all params are specified, then IsValidRequest validation will run

Comment: Easy fix, but for me it seems like some flexibility is missing. CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure; only works inside each Rulefor but not for an each RuleFor inside a Ruleset

Comment: @anveshtummala totally agree with you. I would also expect to have an option to stop validation after any validator in any rule fails

Comment: `CascadeMode.Stop` should be used instead of `CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure` (deprecated).